# How to solve serialize/unserialize errors with zend oauth?

Tags: zend-framework, oauth, linked-list

Using zend oauth, I get the token from linkedin, and serialize it, as per this article

http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/linkedin-and-zendoauth/

but the serialized string has weird characters, which means unserialize isn't working.  Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why that example is serializing / unserializing the token.  I built a linkedin oauth implementation just storing the token normally in the session.

Comment: okay, do you have an example of it somewhere?

Comment: You are serializing, so you can put it in the session? An md5 hash would work better in this case.

Comment: md5 hashes aren't easily reversible...

Comment: Combine with base64_encode/decode

Comment: Hi were you able to solve the problem using Zend? Please post the answer , it would be very helpful as i am facing some what similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet.  It's not pretty, but... yeah.  It runs with the php Oauth plugin, not the Zend Oauth.

```
$oauth = new OAuth(PUBLIC_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
$oauth->setTimestamp(time());

if (!isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['state'] != 1){
    $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
    $request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken("https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?oauth_callback=http://www.*******.com/this_script.php");
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $request_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_SESSION['key'] = $request_token_info['oauth_token'];
    header('Location: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' . $request_token_info['oauth_token'] );
}
else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $oauth->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
    $access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken('https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken');
    $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
    $_SESSION['token'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_REQUEST['action'] = 'lookup';
}

$oauth->setToken($_SESSION['token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
$oauth->fetch("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(summary,educations,positions)", null, GET);//:(educations,positions,summary)", null, GET);

$xmlresult = $oauth->getLastResponse();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use zend :(  Even the tutorial at zend uses serialize method  http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html